# Calculating differences in nested data frames and dividing across another list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse, lubridate

I have split a data frame by two months (june and july). I then nested these two different data frames based on the `ID`. The nested data frame contains a column with the `ID` and a `data` column.

The `data` column contains a list, and the list represents the data for the `ID` that has been split into three 10-day intervals in a month. For example, for the `ID` `A`, the list shows `[[1]]` as the first 10-days, `[[2]]` as the second 10-days, and `[[3]]` as the third 10-days within a month.

For the next component, I want to go down each list for each `ID` and calculate the difference between the minimum `jDate` in `nested_june` and `nested_july`, as shown below for `n1`, `n2`,and `n3`. These differences are then combined into a matrix, `m1`.

Finally, I have a list of two matrices `l1`, and I would like to divide each matrices in the list by `m1`.

Is there a more efficient way calculate the differences and the division of matrices in list?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

f = function(data){
  data %>% mutate(
    new = floor_date(data$date, "10 days"),
    new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)
  ) %>% 
    group_split(new)
}

ID <-  rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), 1000)
date <-  rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
x <-  runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000)
y <-  runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000)

df <- data.frame(date = date, 
                 x = x,
                 y =y,
                 ID)

df$jDate <- julian(as.Date(df$date), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))
df$Month <- month(df$date)

df_june <- filter(df, Month == c("6"))
df_july <- filter(df, Month == c("7"))

nested_june <- tibble(
  df_june
) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, f))

nested_july <- tibble(
  df_july
) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, f))

# Create list of matrices
t1 <- c(100,150,200)
t2 <- c(200,250,350)
t3 <- c(300,350, 400)
mat <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

t1 <- c(150,150,200)
t2 <- c(250,250,350)
t3 <- c(350,350, 400)
mat2 <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

l1 <- list(list(mat), list(mat2))

## Hoping to get a function for everything below here ##

# Calculate difference in days from the first day of one interval to the first 
# day of the second interval and repeat with the other intervals. 

n1 <- c(((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate)))

n2 <- c(((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate)),
        ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate)),
        ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate)))

n3 <-  c(((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[1]]$jDate)),
         ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[2]]$jDate)),
         ((min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate))- min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[3]]$jDate)))
m1 <- cbind(n1,n2,n3)


# Expected output as matrices
l1[[1]][[1]]/m1

l1[[2]][[1]]/m1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `lapply`

```
lapply(l1, function(sub) {sub <- lapply(sub, `/`, m1)
    sub})
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
            t1        t2        t3
[1,]  3.333333  4.761905  6.000000
[2,]  8.333333  8.333333  9.210526
[3,] 20.000000 15.909091 13.333333


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
            t1        t2        t3
[1,]  5.000000  5.952381  7.000000
[2,]  8.333333  8.333333  9.210526
[3,] 20.000000 15.909091 13.333333
```

---

TO create the `matrix`, we can do

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
m2 <-  crossing(i1 = seq_len(ncol(l1[[1]][[1]])),
       i2 = seq_len(ncol(l1[[1]][[1]]))) %>% 
   transmute(new =map2_dbl(i1, i2, 
     ~ min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[.x]]$jDate) - 
        min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[.y]]$jDate))) %>% 
   pull(new) %>%
   matrix(ncol = 3)
```

-checking

```
> m2
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   42   50
[2,]   18   30   38
[3,]   10   22   30
```

OP's 'm1

```
> m1
     n1 n2 n3
[1,] 30 42 50
[2,] 18 30 38
[3,] 10 22 30
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my expected output was very clear. I was hoping to have a function that incorporates the calculation of the differences as well. My actual data set has a large number of `ID`s and I would like to make it a little more automated. Any thoughts?

Comment: I updated the code to show what I was hoping to get help with.

Comment: I think that answers a part of the my question.

Comment: The first part would be the calculation of `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` and getting to creating `m1`. Then the second part is the matrix division that you had provided. Is there anyway to bundle the two parts into one function?

Comment: @JohnHuang Are you looking for only the code change in `n1`, `n2`, `n3` part?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a more effective way to do that.

Comment: @JohnHuang i updated the post

Comment: When there are more than 3 `ID`s I get this error: `Error: Problem with "mutate()" column "new". i "new = map2_dbl(i1, i2, ~min(nested_july[[2]][[1]][[.x]]$jDate) - min(nested_june[[2]][[1]][[.y]]$jDate))". x Invalid index: out of bounds`. Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: @JohnHuang The `map2` is assuming that both `nested_july` and `nested_june` have equal number of rows.  If one of them is different in length, have to make the length same

Comment: @JohnHuang your `l1[[1]]` have only 3 columns, whereas you are still doing only n1, n2, n3..  Wouldn't there by 'n4' as well?

Comment: The n1, n2, and n3 are referring to the intervals that each `ID` is broken up in. Each `ID` should have 3 components in the `list` object under the `data` column of the nested data frame. The number of "n" objects shouldn't vary with the number of `ID`s.

Comment: @JohnHuang please check the update.  I think it is the creation of `crossing` that caused the issue.  It should be based on the sequence of columns in 'l1' element

Comment: @JohnHuang can you please confirm the updatec code which is working